# GTranslate Wordpress plugin not working properly on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've installed [GTranslate](https://gtranslate.io/) plugin into my wordpress site. For a widget look I've chosen the "Flags with language name option" and for a show in menu option I chose "Primary menu" so it would get rendered in my main menu on homepage ([navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhTUR.png)). Everything works fine on PC and different browsers, but when transfering to the mobile phone it completely stops working. Flags are still there but nothing happens when you click on them ([mobile menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbPto.png)). I've noticed that onClick function is missing from the  tag for every language (mobile phone version).
For example:

- this is an onClick function defined when not working with mobile phone
  `onClick="doGTranslate('hr|hr');return false;"`,

but when i switch to mobile version, it's missing.
How could I add this function manually or even better, is there a cleaner solution to this problem?
If pictures are needed, I'll gladly provide, but I think the working scheme is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to define the translation path by

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup');
```

Load translations for wpdocs_theme

```
function wpdocs_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('wpdocs_theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
```

Then install loco translate and it will show you strings that you can tranlslate but you want to define more string for translate, you will _e() to define it and it will be like that

```
<?php _e('string that you want to translate','textdomain') ?>
```

And for showing flags as icon translation on nav menu, you will use multipoly plugin

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but why would I need a new plugin to make the existing one work? GTranslate's functionality is working just fine with a minor bug for a mobile phone version. I just want to know how to fix the bug or create a workaround or if I'm missing something, what?